# Get closest smaller array key of a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I´ve an array `$curvepoint` which is structured like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 57587
            [Pos0] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 57588
            [Pos0] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 57589
            [Pos0] => 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 57590
            [Pos0] => 39
        )
)
```

Now I want to get the closest **smaller** array key in relation to the value `[Pos0]` and a given number.

**Example:**

If I have the variable `$number = 20` the loop should return `1`, because the closest smaller `[Pos0]` value of `20` would be `[Pos0] => 2` which is stored in the `array key 1`.

I´m very unsure how to get the results. I´ve tried to use a combination of array_slice and array_intersect inside a foreach loop.

**Original try:**

```
$number = 20 

foreach ($curvepoint as $test) {

    $two_nearest = array_slice(array_intersect(array_keys($test['Pos0']),range(0,$number)), -2);
    $less_near = $test['Pos0'][$two_nearest[0]];

    echo $less_near;
}
```

**Edited code:**

```
$value = 10;

function findClosestLowerPosition(array $curvepoint , int $value): ?int
{
    $lowerPositions = array_filter(
        array_column($curvepoint , 'Pos0'),
        function ($a) use ($value) {
            return $a < $value;
        }
    );
    if (empty($lowerPositions)) {
        return null;
    }

}

print_r($lowerPositions);
```

Comment: You've posted a specification, but there is no question or problem description in your post. Have you tried to solve this yourself? While we're glad to help you when you're stuck, you're expected to make an effort of your own. If you have tried something, please edit the question to show your effort and explain where and how it failed to do what you want.

Comment: Of course I´ve tried a lot, but I wasn´t even near of a result. Anyways I´ve posted my try/ idea.

Comment: You've completely entangled yourself in doing all of this at once, nesting array functions without a clear idea. If you break this down into smaller problems, it's easier to find a solution. Step 1: extract all values of `Pos0` from the array. Step 2: find closest smaller value (sorting would help). Step 3: find the element that has this value under `Pos0` in the original array. Try to write code for each step and don't worry about optimizing it into a shorter solution.

Comment: Pos0 = 22 is not equal to that number so you need to have a range like how far lower or higher should the number be for example maybe if the pos0 is > than 25 reject it... if =19 take it

Comment: @KevinGales It was specified that the closest *lower* value is to be selected. That is unambiguous.

Comment: Doesn't make sense...if for example the number is 20 and there is pos0=22 pos0=21 pos0 =19... which one will be taken?

Comment: @KevinGales It makes perfect sense. 19 is the only lower value of those you've listed, so that will be the choice. If the choices had been 18, 19 and 21, then 19 would again be chosen because it has the lowest difference from 20, while being smaller than 20.

Comment: Another thing, in your edit you removed the original code. Without it, the question loses context, because you present working code as your attempt. You should have added it after your original code instead of overwriting it.

Comment: I´ve edited my initial post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed solution:

```php
/**
 * Searches for the index of an element that has the closest of all
 * the lower values than the specified one.
 *
 * @return int|null Numeric position of the closest lower element if found,
 * NULL otherwise
 */
function findClosestLowerPosition(array $curvepoints, int $value): ?int
{
    $lowerPositions = array_filter(
        array_column($curvepoints, 'Pos0'),
        function ($a) use ($value) {
            return $a < $value;
        }
    );
    if (empty($lowerPositions)) {
        return null;
    }

    rsort($lowerPositions);
    $closestPosition = $lowerPositions[0];
    foreach ($curvepoints as $key => $curvepoint) {
        if ($curvepoint['Pos0'] === $closestPosition) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

How it works:

- First step gets the values of all the lower positions. This is achieved by first extracting every `Pos0` value through `array_column`. The result of that function is a simple numeric array which is then passed as an argument to `array_filter`, which only filters the values lower than the specified one.
- After that we check if there are any lower values at all - if none are found, our filtered array will be empty. In that case, we return `null` to indicate such a value doesn't exist.
- Once we have the lower values, we sort them in reverse order (greater to lower), in order to place the closest value in the first position of the array, then we get it by accessing the first index (which is always `0` for PHP auto-generated arrays).
- Ultimately, we iterate our original array to locate the element whose value matches the closest one. As soon as a match is found, we return the key of that element.

Note that this whole algorithm assumes there can be no duplicate values of `Pos0`. If your elements can have the same position value, then you need to determine rules how to break the ties.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to understand/ use your code. I´ve a problem. If I take for example `$value = 10;` and `print_r($lowerPositions);` I got no results. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @Berstos Where exactly did you place that line? And what input values did you use?

Comment: I´ve edited my initial post with the code example.

Comment: @Berstos That variable exists only inside the function. If you're insterested in seeing what it looks like, you need to put that debug inside it. And then you have to actually call the function. You might want to read about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: @Berstos Here's a [live test](https://3v4l.org/OJlFE) where you can see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I just need one adjustment. How can I output only the int value. In your example I just need the `3`. Do I have to use `var_export` for this?

Comment: @Berstos No, the function is already returning only the integer value. Outputting is as simple as doing `echo findClosestLowerPosition($curvepoint, 10)`. Or you could store it in a variable if you need to use it in multiple places and then output the variable.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but it always output the array content, too. I´ve edited your example:   [live test](https://3v4l.org/amlV2)

Comment: @Berstos It's because you've left `print_r($lowerPositions);` in there. In the example I included it so you could see how to debug information from inside the function. Just remove that.